# Chrome browser hiding background image in input box on autofill until something is typed in input box

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have input fields on my login page. both input fields (username and password) have image in background. But Chrome browser is hiding the image whenever data  is auto filled. **However, image is shown as soon as I  type something or use backspace key.**

I found answers for this on Stackoverflow but they suggest moving image out of the input box. I can not do that. **I need image in input box only.**
 Can't stick image outside the input box.
Any help will be appreciated.

Need a solution to show image inside input box only in chrome browser on  autofill.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the `:-webkit-autofill` pseudo-class on your selector to override those styles.

Comment: He cannot keep the image he wants using that..

Comment: @MarkoMackic This issue is only there in Chrome browser, working fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Chromes autofill overrides all background styles on input - affected by the autofill.

There's virtually nothing you can do about the yellow auto-fill background overriding your image.

You could set auto-fill off.

-- Edit:

You can of-course change the background color using this format:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px *color* inset;
}
```

Comment: How about the `:-webkit-autofill` pseudo-class?

Comment: You can only change the colour, the OP can't keep the background.

Comment: Notice how I said VIRTUALLY.

Comment: Issue is not the background color but background image not showing up on autofill in Chrome. Image is shown initially but disappers as soon as auto fill data in populated in the fields.

Comment: I stated it want possible to keep the image - currently; and gave an alternative because ismael insisted using the autofill pseudo-class, after Down-Voting my reply......

Comment: As the OP stated, they wanted to keep the background, and you downvoted me for telling them it wasnt possible.

Comment: After some testing, I've seen that those settings are indeed persistant. You're right. Also, you **need** to use `input:-webkit-autofill, input:-webkit-autofill:focus`, since the background changes on focus.